# Boolean Operators in Google Custom Search

Tags: google-custom-search

Given the search terms x,y,z, I want to construct a search query that returns

```
x AND (y OR z)
```

i.e. documents that do contain x and at least one of y and z (or both y and z). Now according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list), I can use the following query

```
q=x&hq=y+OR+z
```

Now I am wondering if this returns what I want or rather

```
(x AND y) OR z
```

I found no way to test that. Any hint (also on how to test it) is very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer

Instead of

```
q=x&hq=y+OR+z
```

try

```
q=y+OR+z&hq=x
```

## Explanation

- `q` It's required.

  > The search expression.
- `hq`

  > Appends the specified query terms to the query, as if they were combined with a logical AND operator.

Comment: Thanks for looking at the question. The problem is, I may have to query terms like "(x OR y) AND (z OR a)" so I still need to know how the parentheses are set.

Comment: Even your answer did not really help, I award the bounty to you.